# Deno array output issue

Tags: arrays, regex, typescript, deno

I am trying to run an API with deno which should show some PDF-Metadata from files from a given directory.
This works fine until the PDF-ID. The PDF-ID should be the last two digits from the file name (eg. jk**03**.pdf, fh**04**.pdf,...). If I run the API, all Metadata is shown as an array inside of an object, unless the ID which creates its own array. Does anyone know how I can implement the ID without creating its own array.

This is what I got until now:

```
import { PDFDocument } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/pdf-lib@^1.11.1?dts';
import { opine, json } from "https://deno.land/x/opine@1.3.4/mod.ts";


const app = opine();
const port = 3000;

app.use(json());

let metaData = new Array();
let pdfData = new Object();

app.get("/pdf", async(req, res) => {
  
  const basePath = './Documents/';
  for (const dirEntry of Deno.readDirSync("./Documents")) {
    
    async function readDocumentMetadata() {
      const filePath = basePath + dirEntry.name
      const existingPdfBytes = await Deno.readFile(filePath);
      const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes, {
        updateMetadata: false 
      });
      
      var pdfId = dirEntry.name.match(/[0-9]+/g)[0];      
      const file = Deno.openSync(filePath, { read: true });
      const fileInfo = Deno.fstatSync(file.rid);

      pdfData = {        
        ID : pdfId[0],
        Name : dirEntry.name,
        Size : fileInfo.size + " Bytes",
        Pages : pdfDoc.getPageCount(),
        CreationDate : pdfDoc.getCreationDate(),
        ModificationDate : pdfDoc.getModificationDate()
      };

      metaData.push(pdfData);        
      
    };
    await readDocumentMetadata();    
  };
  res.json(metaData);
});

console.log("Server running on port", (port));
app.listen(port);
```

This is the error message i get:
{
"resource": "/c:/Users/JK/deno/deno-vs-node/GetAllPdf.ts",
"owner": "deno",
"code": "2531",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Object is possibly 'null'.",
"source": "deno-ts",
"startLineNumber": 25,
"startColumn": 21,
"endLineNumber": 25,
"endColumn": 50
}

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value . `String.prototype.match` returns array of all of matches. If you are sure, that there will be only match, do `const pdfId = dirEntry.name.match(/[0-9]+/g)[0];`

Comment: unfortunately this still gives me an error message: Object is possibly 'null'.

Comment: Could you please paste the code and the error pointing the line where it occurs

Comment: {
 "resource": "/c:/Users/JK/deno/deno-vs-node/PostPDF.ts",
 "owner": "deno",
 "code": "2531",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "Object is possibly 'null'.",
 "source": "deno-ts",
 "startLineNumber": 37,
 "startColumn": 19,
 "endLineNumber": 37,
 "endColumn": 48
}

Comment: This is in line 19: var fields = req.body.usedFields;

Comment: This in line 37: var pdfId = dirEntry.name.match(/[0-9]+/)[0];

Comment: Try `dirEntry?.name?.match(/[0-9]+/g);`

Comment: it's like before...but thanks a lot for your effort

Comment: Please paste the whole error in question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I added .toString() to the end of the line and it works perfectly now;

const pdfId = dirEntry.name.match(/[0-9]+/)?.toString();